# How to monitor cron job using whenever gem and monit tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, rvm, whenever, monit

I am running a cron job that will pull data from facebook and stores in the database using `whenever` gem which is working properly.

I have monit(a monitoring tools) installed in the server and now i would like to monitor that cron job.

I searched a-lot but got nothing handy.
What i have learnt that i need to create a `pid` file for the cron job using bash script and then i need to use that `pid` file in the `monit` configuration.

Can any one tell me how to create `pid` file using `bash script` for the cron job so that i can use that `pid` file in the monit.

i am using `rvm` ruby 2.2.3 and rails 4.1.2.

Comment: Can I provide you with an alternative method?

Comment: sure why not. Thanks for your effort.